Probability of Shuffling a Deck of Cards a Single Time from New Deck Order
I have the following question about shuffling a deck of $52$ playing cards. Most people are astounded by the fact that $52!$ is a really big number, and they say that because it is so big that whenever a deck of cards is shuffled with high probability it is the first time that deck has been in that order.
My question has to do with what happens after the first shuffle. Let's say we start off with a brand new deck of playing cards, so it will be in new card order. If we apply a single riffle shuffle, then how many ways can this be done? But on a more practical note, is it probable that every such shuffle has occurred?
For simplicity, let us label the cards $1,2,3,...,52$. What I mean by a riffle shuffle is that we cut the deck into two piles say $1,...,x$ and $x+1,...,52$. Then we interweave the two decks together to form a sequence that has $1,2,...,x$ and $x+1,x+2,...,52$ as subsequences. At first, I thought that I would just look at all $52$ original cuts, and then count the number of such riffles for each one, but then I realized that I was overcounting as I could always return the cards into new card order for any such shuffle. Thus, I think it requires a bit more attention.
I believe we can just count the number of sequences as described above, but I don't know if there is a clever way of counting them (as I think the order matters since if the first card we put down is $x+1$ rather than $1$ these two scenarios seem to have different yet similar comparisons), and it might seem partitioning this space might be quite difficult. If someone has a clever way of counting this I'd be interested. Furthermore, is such a number going to be big enough that even after a single shuffle we should expect a "new" card order?

Bayer and Diaconis have done a lot of research regarding riffle shuffles: Trailing the Dovetail Shuffle to Its Lair  Diaconis also has some videos on YouTube.

Actually, the number of overcounts with your strategy is easily accounted for: the no-shuffle case (where there is no reordering of the cards) is the only one that is overcounted. Why? Consider two initializations, one that puts $x_1$ in the first pile (and $52 - x_1$ in the other pile), and the other that puts $x_2 > x_1$ in the first pile (and $52 - x_2$ in the other pile). Assuming neither shuffle ends up with no-shuffle, the second shuffle puts the card $x_2 + 1$ before the card $x_2$, whereas by prescription in the first shuffle, the card $x_2 + 1$ must appear after the card $x_2$.
To account for the no-shuffle cases, we can go ahead and simply subtract $1$ for each $x$ case (since this shuffle is possible for any $x$), then add one at the very end (so that we count this trivial scenario exactly once). The number $x$ can range from $0$ to $52$; for each $x$, the number of shuffles, free of restrictions, is simply $\binom{52}{x}$.
Therefore, the number of desired shuffles is
$$\left[ \sum_{x = 0}^{52} \left( \binom{52}{x} - 1 \right) \right] + 1 = 2^{52} - 52$$

Very clean result!

It's interesting that this means that a single riffle shuffle will only generate less than one of every $10^{53}$ possible deck orderings, since $52!$ is just so much larger than $2^{52}-52$. On the other hand, it's known (Diaconis 1986) that seven is sufficiently mixing

@ZubinMukerjee Yes, it is indeed an exceedingly tiny fraction of all possible permutations of a deck. I think that precisely counting reachable permutations after $2$ or more riffle shuffles seems rather daunting.

Perhaps, if someone could help me visualize $2^{52}$. Like how big is this number if we shuffle a single deck, should we expect this to be a new order or not? I know this is more of the soft part of the question.

@StevenCreech $2^{52} (-52)$ is a large number, nowhere near $52!$, but still large (a very conservative estimate of the total number of shuffles ever performed in the history of humankind by humans is around this order of magnitude). Even so, we don't have strong reason to believe that none of these shuffles have been repeated because - and this is key - not all of these results are equally likely to result from a human shuffling cards (you can probably imagine why). So, if I were to guess, we should not expect a single shuffle to result in a completely new order.
